# PostgreSQL server, Blazor project with reference to other projects and i'm getting an error

Tags: .net, postgresql, blazor

So I have multiple projects in this solution. Api and Console that I use well API for APIs and Console for testing some things. I also have Core, Domain and Infrastructure. I recently needed to create an admin dashboard with just a few features for the database, so I created a blazor app and set the configuration and etc and this problem appeared.

I'm using services from Domain project and this is the error I'm getting.

```
WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: System.Net.NameResolution is not supported on this platform.
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Net.NameResolution is not supported on this platform.
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|215_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.PoolingDataSource.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.PoolingDataSource.<Get>g__RentAsync|28_0(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator[[CarDb.Core.Auction, CarDb.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].InitializeReader(Enumerator enumerator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<>c[[CarDb.Core.Auction, CarDb.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].<MoveNext>b__21_0(DbContext _, Enumerator enumerator)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[Enumerator,Boolean](Enumerator state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator[[CarDb.Core.Auction, CarDb.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()
   at CarDb.Domain.Services.AuctionEventDataService.GetEventDtosByName(Int32 pageCount, Int32 page, String provider, String city) in C:\weOwn\metaland\CarDb\Source\CarDb\CarDb.Domain\Services\AuctionEventDataService.cs:line 182
   at CarDb.Dashboard.Core.EventService.GetEventsByProviderCity(Int32 pageCount, Int32 page, String provider, String location) in C:\weOwn\metaland\CarDb\Source\CarDb\CarDb.Dashboard\Core\Services\EventService.cs:line 23
   at CarDb.Dashboard.Components.Events.GetEvents() in C:\weOwn\metaland\CarDb\Source\CarDb\CarDb.Dashboard\Components\Events.razor:line 93
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at MudBlazor.MudBaseButton.OnClickHandler(MouseEventArgs ev)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
window.Module.s.printErr @ blaz
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Blazor has no support for npsql library. My advice would be to avoid directly Configuring in the Blazor app but to try manually configuring the database.

Comment: However you configure it, your password is now public.